# Counting distinct values on millions of rows – Appropriate for NoSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, count, nosql

I've got a web app using a MySQL database with about a dozen columns, and millions of records coded with one-character codes. Cross-sections can be queried by adding a `WHERE` clause:

`SELECT col1, COUNT(col1) AS num
FROM my_table
WHERE col2='U'
GROUP BY col1`

Each page makes about a dozen queries of this sort, one for each column minus the one indicated in the `WHERE` clause.

I do have a caching system, but the data updates every day (adding hundreds of thousands of records), and the process to initially generate the cache is very slow. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the idea of NoSQL, and it seems like there are a bunch of different paradigms for it. So given that each record follows the same format, with no `JOIN`s, would this be an appropriate situation to transition to a NoSQL database? And if so, which one (or which sort) would you recommend?

Edit: I should add that it needs to be PHP compatible.

Answer (score 0):

This a good question.

In my experience, working on millions of rows is always tricky

I think the best way to achieve this is to use specific database which are built to work with this kind of queries.

MySQL, by default, is row oriented and is designed to work as a transactional database (OLTP) which means that it is quick to insert, update, delete small sets of rows. However, it is not designed to work on a large dataset with this kind of queries. So,counting values over millions of rows will take time or sometimes won't give a result (memory overflow...)

Your query is a typical analytical query (contains an aggregation over a column and a GROUP BY). You should consider the use of a column oriented database. These databases are optimized and designed to process large dataset. ([Column oriented database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS))

I never used a NoSQL database to process large dataset because I always needed to have a schema clearly defined and column oriented databases were enough. If you want to use one of them, be sure that it supports the queries you want to do (ie the aggregation type SUM, COUNT,...). Be also aware on how you will insert the new rows each day.